# NPM install + use local modules? on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I created a package.json and added the needed dependencies (grunt, bower, jasmine etc)

when I run

```
npm install
```

it correctly installs all the modules in

```
$pwd/node_modules/*
```

however when I try to USE those modules:

```
bower init; grunt init
```

i get

```
sh.exe: (bower / grunt / w.e) Command not found
```

I can solve this by using

```
npm install -g (package name)
```

but my understanding is the "-g" makes the install global? (is that correct?)

I want to be able to use the packages i installed locally...is this possible?

Comment: Pretty sure when you do `-g` the folder is added to the npm folder which is in the system path. If you want to run bower/grunt from your node_modules folder you need to specify the actual path to that bin file: `node_modules/bower/bin`. Or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npm run-scripts` to create a command which will run the local copies of bower and grunt that you have installed.

In `package.json`, add a key like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "init": "bower init; grunt init"
}
```

Then run the command `npm run init`.

Comment: Thanks @linclark,

is there a way to use those commands outside the npm package.json?